# expression-engine : Fancybox + EE?

Tags: content-management-system, fancybox, expressionengine, content-management

I am having a problem using fancybox with expression engine.

Basically I have different galleries set-up using matrix plugin. Each gallery has around 10 images. Basically I want the thumbnail to open up fancybox and fancybox to be able to scroll through the images in that matrix entry/gallery.

Sounds simple but I can’t seem to get fancybox to scroll through the images, it just stays on the first image.

This is my code for the thumbnails:

```
<ul id="image_gallery">
              {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery_images"}
               <li>
                    <a class="grouped_elements" href="{title_permalink='gallery/view'}" rel="{title}">
                    {gallery_image limit="1"}
                        {exp:imgsizer:size src="{image}" width="200px" height="180px"}
                            <img src="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt="" />
                    {/exp:imgsizer:size}
                    {/gallery_image}
                    </a>
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                </li>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
        </ul>
```

This is my code for the fancybox template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery_images"}
<ul id="img_gallery">
{gallery_image}
<li>
    {exp:imgsizer:size src="{image}" width="650px" height="500px"}
    <img src="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt=""/>
    {/exp:imgsizer:size}
</li>
{/gallery_image}
</ul>{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Everything works fine except for the image scrolling.

I’d appreciate any help!

Comment: This is not an EE problem and you should post your Fancybox script.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the output of your ExpressionEngine tags, it's difficult to understand where the problem is. However, your problem may be as simple as making sure all of the images in a *gallery* share the same [HTML relationship attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/link/rel).

[Fancybox Galleries](http://fancybox.net/howto) are created from elements who share the same `rel=""` attribute:

```
<a class="gallery" rel="set_1" href="#"><img src="1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="gallery" rel="set_1" href="#"><img src="2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="gallery" rel="set_1" href="#"><img src="3.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<script>
    $('a.gallery').fancybox();
</script>
```

In looking over your code, you're using the ExpressionEngine `{title}` tag as the `rel=""` attribute.

Since the title of your channel entry likely contains spaces and other special characters, a better choice would be to use the [URL Title](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/variables.html#var_title_permalink) field, `{title_permalink}`.

The `{title_permalink}` tag converts the channel entry title to be *URL-safe* using either hyphens or underscores as character separators (using the **Word Separator for URL Titles** setting in the [Global Channel Preferences](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide//cp/admin/content_admin/global_channel_preferences.html)).

Your updated thumbnail code would then be:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" href="{title_permalink='gallery/view'}" rel="{title_permalink}">
    <img src="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt="" />
</a>
```

If this doesn't work, perhaps you can provide a more complete code sample such as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Pastie](http://jsfiddle.net/) to help us understand where the problem may be.